# Error with Deeply Equal To?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am currently using FreeCodeCamp to try to learn basic JavaScript scripting. The problem that I am currently working on is:

http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-map-the-debris.

The problem involves using OOP to solve a specific task (calculating orbital periods from the given altitude).

My code is as follows:

```
 function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  var GM = 398600.4418;
  var earthRadius = 6367.4447;

  this.arr = arr;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     var altitude = this.arr[i]["avgAlt"] + earthRadius;
     var calc = Math.round((2*Math.PI) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(altitude,3) / GM),1);

     this.arr[i]["avgAlt"] = calc;
  }

 return this.arr;
}



orbitalPeriod([{name : "sputkin", avgAlt : 35873.5553}]);
```

The issue is not with my calculations. Rather, when I submit my code, I get: "expected [ { name: 'sputkin', avgAlt: 86400 } ] to deeply equal [ Array (1) ]". Does anyone know why it is telling me that I should return an Array (1)?

Answer (score 3):

The test suite is expecting the return array to contain an object with the properties `name` and `orbitalPeriod` - yours is returning an array containing an object with the properties `name` and `avgAlt`.

Side note, don't use the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword unless you're sure as to what it does - and I promise you it does not do what you think it does here.

Here's the solution, compare it with yours. Your calculations were correct, so good job on that part.

```
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  var GM = 398600.4418,
      earthRadius = 6367.4447,
      output = [], altitude, calc;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     altitude = arr[i].avgAlt + earthRadius;
     calc = Math.round((2*Math.PI) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(altitude,3) / GM));

     output.push({
       name: arr[i].name,
       orbitalPeriod: calc
     });
  }

 return output;
}

orbitalPeriod([{name : "sputkin", avgAlt : 35873.5553}]);
```

Bonus note: [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) only takes one parameter.

---

Bonus answer:

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) makes this super clean, if we're not tuning for performance.

```
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  var GM = 398600.4418,
      earthRadius = 6367.4447;

 return arr.map(function (o) {
   return {
     name: o.name,
     orbitalPeriod: Math.round((2 * Math.PI) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(o.avgAlt + earthRadius, 3) / GM))
   };
 });
}

orbitalPeriod([{name : "sputkin", avgAlt : 35873.5553}]);
```